# Use different array based on the current date, using else if

Tags: php, arrays

```
function UTIsOpen() {
$status = FALSE;
//get current East Coast US time
$timeObject = new DateTime('America/Chicago');
$timestamp = $timeObject->getTimeStamp();
$currentTime = $timeObject->setTimestamp($timestamp)->format('H:i A');

$today = date("M-d-Y");

//January 2nd – January 20th
$janA = date("M-d-Y", mktime(0,0,0,1,1,2018));
$janB = date("M-d-Y", mktime(0,0,0,1,21,2018));
 //January 22nd – February 10th
$janC = date("M-d-Y", mktime(0,0,0,1,21,2018));
$febB = date("M-d-Y", mktime(0,0,0,2,11,2018));
//February 12th – March 3rd
$febC = date("M-d-Y", mktime(0,0,0,2,11,2018));
$marA = date("M-d-Y", mktime(0,0,0,3,4,2018));
//March 5th – April 16th
$marB = date("M-d-Y", mktime(0,0,0,3,4,2018));
$aprA = date("M-d-Y", mktime(0,0,0,4,17,2018));
//April 17th
$aprB = date("M-d-Y", mktime(0,0,0,4,17,2018));

if (($today > $janA) && ($today < $janB)) {
$storeSchedule = array( //January 2nd – January 20th
  'Mon' =>
    array('08:00 AM' => '06:00 PM'),
  'Tue' =>
    array('08:00 AM' => '06:00 PM'),
  'Wed' =>
    array('08:00 AM' => '06:00 PM'),
  'Thu' =>
    array('08:00 AM' => '06:00 PM'),
  'Fri' =>
    array('08:00 AM' => '06:00 PM'),
  'Sat' =>
    array('09:00 AM' => '03:00 PM')
 );
}
elseif (($today > $janC) && ($today < $febB)) {
$storeSchedule = array( //January 22nd – February 10th
  'Mon' =>
    array('07:00 AM' => '10:00 PM'),
  'Tue' =>
    array('07:00 AM' => '10:00 PM'),
  'Wed' =>
    array('07:00 AM' => '10:00 PM'),
  'Thu' =>
    array('07:00 AM' => '10:00 PM'),
  'Fri' =>
    array('07:00 AM' => '10:00 PM'),
  'Sat' =>
    array('08:00 AM' => '06:00 PM')  
 );
}
elseif (($today > $febC) && ($today < $marA)) {
$storeSchedule = array( //February 12th – March 3rd
  'Mon' =>
    array('08:00 AM' => '08:00 PM'),
  'Tue' =>
    array('08:00 AM' => '08:00 PM'),
  'Wed' =>
    array('08:00 AM' => '08:00 PM'),
  'Thu' =>
    array('08:00 AM' => '08:00 PM'),
  'Fri' =>
    array('08:00 AM' => '08:00 PM'),
  'Sat' =>
    array('09:00 AM' => '04:00 PM')
 );
}
elseif (($today > $marB) && ($today < $aprA)) {
 $storeSchedule = array( //March 5th – April 16th
  'Mon' =>
    array('08:00 AM' => '06:00 PM'),
  'Tue' =>
    array('08:00 AM' => '06:00 PM'),
  'Wed' =>
    array('08:00 AM' => '06:00 PM'),
  'Thu' =>
    array('08:00 AM' => '06:00 PM'),
  'Fri' =>
    array('08:00 AM' => '06:00 PM'),
  'Sat' =>
    array('09:00 AM' => '02:00 PM')
 );
}
elseif ($today == $aprB) {
 $storeSchedule = array( //April 17th
  'Mon' =>
    array('08:00 AM' => '05:00 PM'),
  'Tue' =>
    array('08:00 AM' => '08:00 PM'),
  'Wed' =>
    array('08:00 AM' => '05:00 PM'),
  'Thu' =>
    array('08:00 AM' => '05:00 PM'),
  'Fri' =>
    array('08:00 AM' => '05:00 PM')
 );
}
else {
 $storeSchedule = array(
  'Mon' =>
    array('08:00 AM' => '05:00 PM'),
  'Tue' =>
    array('08:00 AM' => '05:00 PM'),
  'Wed' =>
    array('08:00 AM' => '05:00 PM'),
  'Thu' =>
    array('08:00 AM' => '05:00 PM'),
  'Fri' =>
    array('08:00 AM' => '05:00 PM')
 );
};

// loop through time ranges for current day
foreach ($storeSchedule[date('D', $timestamp)] as $startTime => $endTime) {

// create time objects from start/end times and format as string (24hr AM/PM)
$startTime = DateTime::createFromFormat('h:i A', $startTime)->format('H:i A');
$endTime = DateTime::createFromFormat('h:i A', $endTime)->format('H:i A');

// check if current time is within the range
if (($startTime < $currentTime) && ($currentTime < $endTime)) {
    $status = TRUE;
    echo '<a href="tel:383-327-1910" id="number_link"><span itemprop="telephone">383-327-1910</span></a>';
  } else {
    echo "Phone support is only available during business hours.";
  }
 }
}
```

I am new to PHP and what I am trying to achieve on my code above is use the array based on the current date. What I am having trouble is when I set the date to Jan 21,2018 (to test) it is using the wrong array. Can someone good at explaining help my little knowledge about coding? I know this multiple else if is already bad and should be converted to switch - which I don't know yet how to do - thank you.

Comment: Is the machine you are changing the date the server? The client date is irrelevant on that code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code fails on Jan 21st because even though `$janB` and `$janC` are set to that date, both of your conditional statements exclude Jan 21st.

```
if (($today > $janA) && ($today < $janB)) {
// This one is only true if $today is before Jan 21st
}
elseif (($today > $janC) && ($today < $febB)) {
// This one is only true if $today is after Jan 21st
}
```

You are doing a lot of unnecessary DateTime conversions in your code.

As you are varying working hours on a weekly basis then you could just check the week number, day number and hour number instead of creating lots of dates, like this:

```
$day = date("N");  // Day as a number, 1 = Monday, 7 = Sunday
$hour = date("G"); // Hour as a number, 24 hour clock
$week = date("W");  // Week of the year as a number, 1 - 52
switch ($week) { // Check what week number it is
    case 01:
    case 02:
    case 03:  // Schedule for first three weeks
    $storeSchedule = array('Week' => array('open'=> 8, 'close' => 18),'Sat' => array('open'=> 9, 'close' => 15));
        break;  // Hours are the same Mon - Fri, so just save 1 value for week days and one for Sat. Use hour from 24 hour clock
    case 04:
    case 05:
    case 06:
    $storeSchedule = // Hours here
        break;
    case 07:
    case 08:
    case 09:
    $storeSchedule = // Hours here
        break;
}
if (date('M-d-Y') == date("M-d-Y", strtotime("17 apr 2018"))) {
    $storeSchedule = array('Week' => array('open'=> 8, 'close' => 20));
}
if ($day < 6) { 
    $hours = $storeSchedule['Week'];  // Set hours for weekday
}
if ($day == 6) { // Unless its Sat
    $store = $storeSchedule['Sat'];
}
if ($hour >= $store['open'] && $hour < $store['close'] && $day != 7) {  // Check its not Sunday and between open and close hours
    echo '<a href="tel:383-327-1910" id="number_link"><span itemprop="telephone">383-327-1910</span></a>';
}
else {
    echo "Phone support is only available during business hours.";
}
```

Comment: Thank you sir, not only you corrected my code you also taught me how to use switch with easy to understand comments! can't thank you enough sir! one last question, can I add a specific date for the switch like the $aprB = date("M-d-Y", mktime(0,0,0,4,17,2018)); on my old code?

Comment: A switch is just a neater way of writing multiple `if` statements to be compared against the same value. So in my code it's checking the value of `$week`. To include the specific date you could rewrite it all using `True` as the value to check but you would have to change all the `case` conditions to include an expression to evaluate, like `case ($week ==01):` etc. Because it's only one extra value you need to check it would be better to just add it below the switch as an additional `if` statement

Comment: I've edited my answer to include an example of your additional date. You may find `strtotime` more user friendly than `mktime` as you can just type the date you want. If you have normal opening hours you can also add a `default` clause at the end of the switch statement which wil match if none of the other cases do